# Rich text format (with formatting tags) in Excel to unformatted text

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, rtf

I have approx. 12000 cells in excel containing RTF (including formatting tags). I need to parse them to get to the unformatted text.

This is the example of one of the cells with text:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deflang1060\ftnbj\uc1
{\fonttbl{\f0 \froman \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1 \fswiss \fcharset238
Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0 ;}
{\stylesheet{\fs24\cf2\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\cf2\cb1 Default Paragraph Font;}}
\paperw11908\paperh16833\margl1800\margr1800\margt1440\margb1440\headery720\footery720
\deftab720\formshade\aendnotes\aftnnrlc\pgbrdrhead\pgbrdrfoot
\sectd\pgwsxn11908\pghsxn16833\marglsxn1800\margrsxn1800\margtsxn1440\margbsxn1440
\headery720\footery720\sbkpage\pgncont\pgndec
\plain\plain\f1\fs24\pard TPR 0160 000\par IPR 0160 000\par OB-R-02-28\par}
```

And all I really need is this:

```
TPR 0160 000
IPR 0160 000
OB-R-02-28
```

The problem with simple looping over the cells and removing unnecessary formatting is, that not everything in those 12000 cells is as straightforward as this is. So I would need to manually inspect many different versions and write several variations; and still at the end there would be a lot of manual work to do.

But if I copy the contents of one cell to empty text document and save it as RTF, then open it with MS Word, it instantly parses the text and I get exactly what I want. Unfortunately it's extremely inconvenient to do so for a 12000 cells.

So I was thinking about VBA macro, to move cell contents to Word, force parsing and then copy the result back to the originating cell. Unfortunately I'm not really sure how to do it.

Does anybody has any idea? Or a different approach? I will be really grateful for a solution or a push in the right direction.

TNX!

Comment: easier alternative using the Microsoft Rich Textbox Control http://stackoverflow.com/a/42579833/1383168

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you did want to go down the route of using Word to parse the text, this function should help you out. As the comments suggest, you'll need a reference to the MS Word Object Library.

```
Function ParseRTF(strRTF As String) As String
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document 'Ref: Microsoft Word 11.0 Object Library'
Dim f     As Integer       'Variable to store the file I/O number'

'File path for a temporary .rtf file'
Const strFileTemp = "C:\TempFile_ParseRTF.rtf"

'Obtain the next valid file I/O number'
f = FreeFile

'Open the temp file and save the RTF string in it'
Open strFileTemp For Output As #f
    Print #f, strRTF
Close #f

'Open the .rtf file as a Word.Document'
Set wdDoc = GetObject(strFileTemp)

'Read the now parsed text from the Word.Document'
ParseRTF = wdDoc.Range.Text

'Delete the temporary .rtf file'
Kill strFileTemp

'Close the Word connection'
wdDoc.Close False
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Function
```

You could call it for each of your 12,000 cells using something similar to this:

```
Sub ParseAllRange()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strRTF  As String

For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A12000")

    'Parse the cell contents'
    strRTF = ParseRTF(CStr(rngCell))

    'Output to the cell one column over'
    rngCell.Offset(0, 1) = strRTF
Next
End Sub
```

The ParseRTF function takes about a second to run (on my machine at least), so for 12,000 cells this will work out at about three and a half hours.

---

Having thought about this problem over the weekend, I was sure there was a better (quicker) solution for this.

I remembered the RTF capabilities of the clipboard, and realised that a class could be created that would copy RTF data to the clipboard, paste to a word doc, and output the resulting plain text. The benefit of this solution is that the word doc object would not have to be opened and closed for each rtf string; it could be opened before the loop and closed after.

Below is the code to achieve this. It is a Class module named clsRTFParser.

```
Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" _
                (ByVal wFlags&, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" _
                (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" _
                (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" _
                (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" _
                (ByVal Hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function RegisterClipboardFormat Lib "user32" Alias _
                "RegisterClipboardFormatA" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" _
                (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

'---'

Dim wdDoc As Word.Document 'Ref: Microsoft Word 11.0 Object Library'

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set wdDoc = New Word.Document
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
wdDoc.Close False
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub

'---'

Private Function CopyRTF(strCopyString As String) As Boolean
Dim hGlobalMemory  As Long
Dim lpGlobalMemory As Long
Dim hClipMemory    As Long
Dim lngFormatRTF   As Long

'Allocate and copy string to memory'
hGlobalMemory = GlobalAlloc(&H42, Len(strCopyString) + 1)
lpGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hGlobalMemory)
lpGlobalMemory = lstrcpy(lpGlobalMemory, strCopyString)

'Unlock the memory and then copy to the clipboard'
If GlobalUnlock(hGlobalMemory) = 0 Then
    If OpenClipboard(0&) <> 0 Then
        Call EmptyClipboard

        'Save the data as Rich Text Format'
        lngFormatRTF = RegisterClipboardFormat("Rich Text Format")
        hClipMemory = SetClipboardData(lngFormatRTF, hGlobalMemory)

        CopyRTF = CBool(CloseClipboard)
    End If
End If
End Function

'---'

Private Function PasteRTF() As String
Dim strOutput As String

'Paste the clipboard data to the wdDoc and read the plain text result'
wdDoc.Range.Paste
strOutput = wdDoc.Range.Text

'Get rid of the new lines at the beginning and end of the document'
strOutput = Left(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 2)
strOutput = Right(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 2)

PasteRTF = strOutput
End Function

'---'

Public Function ParseRTF(strRTF As String) As String
If CopyRTF(strRTF) Then
    ParseRTF = PasteRTF
Else
    ParseRTF = "Error in copying to clipboard"
End If
End Function
```

You could call it for each of your 12,000 cells using something similar to this:

```
Sub CopyParseAllRange()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strRTF  As String

'Create new instance of clsRTFParser'
Dim RTFParser As clsRTFParser
Set RTFParser = New clsRTFParser

For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A12000")

    'Parse the cell contents'
    strRTF = RTFParser.ParseRTF(CStr(rngCell))

    'Output to the cell one column over'
    rngCell.Offset(0, 1) = strRTF
Next
End Sub
```

I have simulated this using example RTF strings on my machine. For 12,000 cells it took two and a half minutes, a much more reasonable time frame!

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry it took one year... Back then your answer was a pointer to the right direction, so I shoud accept it. Well, better late than never. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to parse every cell with regular expression and leave only the content you need.

Every RTF control code start with "\" and ends with space, without any additional space between. "{}" are use for grouping. If your text won't contain any, you can just remove them (the same for ";"). So now you stay with your text and some unnecessary words as "Arial", "Normal" etc. You can build the dictionary to remove them also. After some tweaking, you will stay with only the text you need.

Look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more information and great tool to write RegExp's (RegexBuddy - unfortunately it isn't free, but it's worth the money. AFAIR there is also trial).

UPDATE: Of course, I don't encourage you to do it manually for every cell. Just iterate through active range:
Refer this thread:
[SO: About iterating through cells in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73785/how-to-iterate-through-all-the-cells-in-excel-vba-or-vsto-2005)

Personally, I'll give a try to this idea:

```
Sub Iterate()
   For Each Cell in ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
      'Do something
   Next
End Sub
```

And how to use RegExp's in VBA (Excel)?

Refer:
[Regex functions in Excel](http://lispy.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/using-regex-functions-in-excel/)
and
[Regex in VBA](http://www.tmehta.com/regexp/)

Basically you've to use VBScript.RegExp object through COM.

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. But I would really like to avoid several passes if possible. This table is infact an export from SQL DB and I will have to do this parsing for quite a few times before the end of the year. 

I already have a partial solution. I have a working VBA script to remove large portion of RTF formatting, but leaves some (just to be on the safe side). Then I have to Find/Replace very many strange tags and stuff.

So, a complete solution would be very handy. Doing manual procedure once is a bit boring. Doing it 5 or even 10 times is absolutely nerve-wrecking.

Comment: I didn't mention to do it manually for each cell. Just iterate through all cells and parse every cell with your custom script. I'll update my comment with more thoughts.

Comment: Oh and about several passes. If you split your task into stages you have to code them in your custom cell parser and run all during one pass! I don't know your data, but I think it'll be enough to have a cunning regular expression so you'll be able to finish it during one stage/pass.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the solutions here require a reference to the MS Word Object Library. Playing with the cards I am dealt, I found a solution that does not rely on it. It strips RTF tags, and other fluff like font tables and stylesheets, all in VBA. It might be helpful to you. I ran it across your data, and other than the whitespace, I get the same output as what you expected.

Here is the code.

First, something to check if a string is alphanumeric or not. Give it a string that's one character long. This function is used to work out delimitation here and there.

```
Public Function Alphanumeric(Character As String) As Boolean
   If InStr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-", Character) Then
       Alphanumeric = True
   Else
       Alphanumeric = False
   End If
End Function
```

Next up is to remove an entire group. I use this to remove font tables and other rubbish.

```
Public Function RemoveGroup(RTFString As String, GroupName As String) As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim Count As Integer

    I = InStr(RTFString, "{\" & GroupName)

    ' If the group was not found in the RTF string, then just return that string unchanged.
    If I = 0 Then
        RemoveGroup = RTFString
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Otherwise, we will need to scan along, from the start of the group, until we find the end of the group.
    ' The group is delimited by { and }. Groups may be nested, so we need to count up if we encounter { and
    ' down if we encounter }. When that count reaches zero, then the end of the group has been found.
    J = I
    Do
        If Mid(RTFString, J, 1) = "{" Then Count = Count + 1
        If Mid(RTFString, J, 1) = "}" Then Count = Count - 1
        J = J + 1
    Loop While Count > 0

    RemoveGroup = Replace(RTFString, Mid(RTFString, I, J - I), "")

End Function
```

Okay, and this function removes any tags.

```
Public Function RemoveTags(RTFString As String) As String
    Dim L As Long
    Dim R As Long
    L = 1
    ' Search to the end of the string.
    While L < Len(RTFString)
        ' Append anything that's not a tag to the return value.
        While Mid(RTFString, L, 1) <> "\" And L < Len(RTFString)
            RemoveTags = RemoveTags & Mid(RTFString, L, 1)
            L = L + 1
        Wend
    
        'Search to the end of the tag.
        R = L + 1
        While Alphanumeric(Mid(RTFString, R, 1)) And R < Len(RTFString)
            R = R + 1
        Wend
        L = R
    Wend
End Function
```

We can remove curly braces in the obvious way:

```
Public Function RemoveBraces(RTFString As String) As String
    RemoveBraces = Replace(RTFString, "{", "")
    RemoveBraces = Replace(RemoveBraces, "}", "")
End Function
```

Once you have the functions above copy-pasted into your module, you can create a function that uses them to strip away any stuff you don't need or want. The following works perfectly in my case.

```
Public Function RemoveTheFluff(RTFString As String) As String
    RemoveTheFluff = Replace(RTFString, vbCrLf, "")
    RemoveTheFluff = RemoveGroup(RemoveTheFluff, "fonttbl")
    RemoveTheFluff = RemoveGroup(RemoveTheFluff, "colortbl")
    RemoveTheFluff = RemoveGroup(RemoveTheFluff, "stylesheet")
    RemoveTheFluff = RemoveTags(RemoveBraces(RemoveTheFluff))
End Function
```

I hope this helps. I wouldn't use it in a word processor or anything, but it might do for scraping data if that's what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your post made it sound as if each RTF document was stored in a single Excell cell. If so, then

[Solution using .Net Framework RichTextBox control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48605635/9307380)

will convert the RTF in each cell to plain text in 2 lines of code (after a little system configuration to get the right .tlb file to allow reference to the .Net Framework). Put the cell value in *rtfsample* and

```
Set miracle = New System_Windows_Forms.RichTextBox
With miracle
    .RTF = rtfText
    PlainText = .TEXT
End With
```