# vba script RTF text to unformatted text in excel not always working

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using the answer of this link [Rich text format (with formatting tags) in Excel to unformatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673025/rich-text-format-with-formatting-tags-in-excel-to-unformatted-text)
(Nossidge, thank you for this script) for years to convert rtf text to unformatted text, never encountered any problems.

I integrated this script in a script to extract  a parts list from our erp system (sql database) in multiple languages and create a project based excel file. Most languages are stored as normal text in the database, but Russian and Chinese can only be stored as RTF text in the database otherwise you only see ?????? in our erp system.

I was working with office 2013 and windows 7.
A couple of months ago we upgraded the computer from windows 7 to windows 10, still using office 2013.

Since then I get at random this error:

> Run-time error '4198': command failed

it stops at the line

```
    'Parse the cell contents'
    strRTF = RTFParser.ParseRTF(CStr(Range("P" & ActiveCell.Row)))
```

if I klik debug and then continue (script) it does make of the rtf text normal text in the cell.

This is very annoying and time inefficient if you get this error +50 times in a list with +1000 rtf text strings/cells

I have tried to solve this problem but I haven't been able, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know which command is failing?

Comment: I added the line of script where I get the error