# Convert RTF code in an excel sheet to Readable Text

Tags: sql, excel, vba, rtf

So I have a database I am constantly pulling data from into an Excel sheet. One of the columns is RTF notes which when pulled display in the excel cell with 'gibberish' around the body of text. If I double click on the cell as if to edit it and press enter Excel automatically updates the cell and displays the body without the 'gibberish'. Is there a way to automate this process either a formula, a text setting or VBA code that could automate entering the cell to register that and auto convert the field?

Additional info I can add from solutions I've tried so far. I am using Office 365 and am using a 64 bit pc

Example of the data:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 System;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 This is an example of test information 
\par 
\par Here is more text\b\f1 
\par }
```

Comment: A quick search found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673025

Comment: @CLR I know I had originally looked at that one and the reason I added that mine is a 64 bit system is that the answer there relies on 32 bit systems only. It generates a error otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 64bit system and a slight rework of the first answer in [stackoverflow.com/questions/1673025](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673025) works for me:

```
Sub ConvertRTFcell()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document 
    Dim ff As Integer
    fn = "C:\temp\File_ParseRTF.rtf"
    For Each rngCell In Range("P10:P15")
        If Trim(rngCell.Value) Like "{*}" Then
            ff = FreeFile
            Open fn For Output As #ff
            Print #ff, rngCell.Value
            Close #ff
            Set wdDoc = GetObject(fn)
            rngCell.Value = wdDoc.Range.Text
            wdDoc.Close False
            Kill fn
            Set wdDoc = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You'll need Word installed, and a reference in Excel project to *Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library'*

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly though i had to remove your IF statement. This is causing me other issues but if I include it it actually doesn't recognize the cells even though they meet the criteria. Without it though rerunning the macro is painful

Comment: Glad that helped. Re: the pattern, maybe just try `IF rngCell.value like "*rtf*"`, or one of the other common keywords?

Comment: Fresh eyes and that got it!!