# Sort column and rows using color showed in image in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

I Posted one picture here. I want to do some filtering functionalities. If I do a click on yellow color in sheet then it will show only yellow color cells and other cell won`t show up . Any Idea How can I do this  ?

Thanks in Advance .

[image]

Comment: you can right click on the table and select filter on color. or is that not the desired outcome?

Comment: @JBom yeah but slight different from it. When click on particular cell color let`s say yellow here then it will show only yellow color row/column and other should be disable or white color is that possible in ms excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, you are unable to hide individual cells in excel, however you can "hide" cells by either deleting its contents, or making its contents white/invisible.

[Hiding Individual Cells](http://excel.tips.net/T002880_Hiding_Individual_Cells.html)

If this is OK for you, I would create a:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

and get the cell's color:

```
ActiveCell.Interior.Color
```

and then iterate through all other cells:

[Iterating Through Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73785/how-to-iterate-through-all-the-cells-in-excel-vba-or-vsto-2005)

deleting cell contents/changing font color if the cell color does not match the defined color.

You may be able to first sort the cells by color, so that all identical colors are in the same row, and then when you run through the cells, you can just hide the whole row if any cell in it is the incorrect color.

This is obviously not a complete solution, and you would have to change some things around for it to work for your needs.