# Excel VBA iterate over all used cells and substitute their values

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first time ever working with VBA and Excel and my problem is probably caused by a big lack of knowledge on my part.

I have a one column list of city names (*containing 800 items, hence I'm looking to automatically replace them*) and some chunks of text in which the term "cityname" occurs multiple times and needs to be replaced by the correct city name, which in my setup would be the **value of the first column cell in the same row**.

So I found this: [How to iterate through all the cells in Excel VBA or VSTO 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73785/how-to-iterate-through-all-the-cells-in-excel-vba-or-vsto-2005)

and found the **InStr** and **Substitute** functions by looking through the Excel VBA reference.

Using the iteration like this works fine:

```
Sub MySubstitute()
    Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
            If InStr(cell.Value, "cityname") > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Hello World!"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I get a message box for every "cityname" in my sheet (*a test sheet with only 2 rows*).

However when I add what I really want to achieve I get a **Runtime Error (1004)**:

```
Sub MySubstitute()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If InStr(cell.Value, "cityname") > 0 Then
            cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell.Value, "cityname", Cells(cell.Row, A))
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

So I guess something in that line is wrong but I can't figure out what. Any hints to what my mistake is are appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
 cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell.Value, "cityname", Cells(cell.Row, A))
```

by

```
 cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell.Value, "cityname", Cells(cell.Row, 1))
```

Comment: it could also be `Cells(cell.Row, "A")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Range.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) Method and replace all at once no need to iterate.

```
Sub MySubstitute()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    rng.Replace "cityname", "correctcityname", xlPart
End Sub
```

Comment: This would work if I had a single correct city name. But I have a list of 800, so each time the correct one has to be taken from the first cell of the same row as the current cell, hence the need for iteration. Thanks for the effort though!