# Excel VBA How to edit every cell with formula on the sheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm pretty new with Excel VBA, so excuse me, if this question is simple :)
I've spent half a day trying to google some simple and elegant way to solve my little question, but haven't succeeded yet.

**The problem: I need to go through every cell with formula on the sheet and change the formula in some way (doesn't matter how).**

So, what is the most efficient way to do so?

By now, I wrote some code lines that work with UsedRange, but they work incorrectly, because I haven't figured out how to identify the first cell in the UsedRange

Many thanks in advance

Regards,
PG

Comment: 1- Post your code, 2- What exactly is the problem - why do you need the first cell if you have the `UsedRange` ? If you want to iterate over the whole `usedRange`, [this will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73785/how-to-iterate-through-all-the-cells-in-excel-vba-or-vsto-2005).

Comment: I read on MSDN, that UsedRange is read-only.

Comment: Checked now, whether I can actually change the cells in usedRange. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    For each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        ' do what you need with cell
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I need!