# Searching for greater than 1 value in a column Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Anybody knows here how to look for a value that is greater than 1 in a column?

```
Set fileSheet = wb.ActiveSheet
fileSheet.Name = "Test"


Set rng = fileSheet.Range("D:D")
Set rngFound = rng.Find(">1")

If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No value"
End If
```

I'm trying to do it that way, but I know that if you put a double qoute, it will be treated as a String, so is there any way I can look for a greater than 1 value before filtering it? Please note that I will be working with a column that has thousands of data.

Comment: You can't use Find that way. Probably have to loop, perhaps using specialcells to limit the range to be searched. Or could add a helper column and filter on that.

Comment: @SJR Owhh, if I have to loop, it might take some time, and can cause the excel to freeze.

Comment: Use filtering, that is decent up to a tens of thousands of rows. Record macro of an autofilter, and work your way up from there.

Comment: Is it an option to sort the column?

Comment: @SJR Nope, I don't have to sort the column, all I need is to check if the column has >1 value :)

Comment: Suggested code below. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @SJR I have to find values that is greater than 1, if it has greater than 1 values, then filter and apply a formula. May be I'm going to create a function to check if the column has >1 value

Comment: Why not just use autofilter then? Or do you have blank rows?

Comment: Yes, also some rows are blank :)

Answer (score 2):

This should speed things up, assuming the cells contain numbers rather than formulas. An array would be much quicker, but depends what exactly you are trying to achieve.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, filesheet As Worksheet, Rng As Range

Set filesheet = wb.ActiveSheet
filesheet.Name = "Test"

Set Rng = filesheet.Range("D1", filesheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

For Each r In Rng
    If r.Value > 1 Then
        'do whatever
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two for cycles for the index of last column and row like this.
Or, use the active sheet's range's foreach cycle.
More info:
[How to iterate through all the cells in Excel VBA or VSTO 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73785/how-to-iterate-through-all-the-cells-in-excel-vba-or-vsto-2005)

Answer (score 0):

displays cells that are > 1 for the range D1 to D100

```
Dim i As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

For i = 1 To 100

    If .Cells(i,4).Value > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Value Found! Cell D " & i
    End If

Next i

End With
```

Comment: Thanks. But I file has thousands of rows with data. This may cause the file to crash.

Comment: give it a try and let me know what happends

Comment: This works, but is not applicable for a file that has thousands of data

Comment: You never specified that in the question

Comment: Doesn't this check the same range 100 times? You don't use `i` in the checking, only the message. The `>1` is always looking at the same range.

Comment: @sourceCode Updated my question :)